# HTML: Photo-grid HTML script with static text section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a team section for a firm website. I'd like to have a grid of team photos with a box next to the grid which is updated whenever I click on a person's picture, something like this:

[image: Team Page]

The website is pure html/css, current version can be seen here: http://mgvd.co/thinktank 
I'm wondering if someone can suggest a simple solution to implement this feature - some HTML code snippet or the sort.

Thanks!

Comment: The solution is AJAX. You can do it with javascript or by using jQuery.

Comment: @Alvaro, why ajax? All texts can be hidden on same page?

Comment: If you want to do that instead, then just javascript and jQuery by using `$.show` and `$.hide` with some logic under it.

Comment: If you want HTML and CSS only, look into the `:target` selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<img class="myImg" id="pic1" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/" />
<img class="myImg" id="pic2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/" />
<div id="info"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//object with image id and description to show
var info = {
    'pic1': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    'pic2': 'consetetur sadipscing elitr'
};

//get all images
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg') || document.querySelectorAll('myImg');

//set eventhandler for each image
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
         //get the description from the object
         document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = info[event.target.id];
    }, false);
}
```

<kbd>[JSfiddle DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/F4B7x/)</kbd>

Comment: thanks Alex! This is exactly what we needed! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This example may help you: http://www.bootply.com/116656

Basically you create 2 containers `grid` and `descriptions` with child elements for the images and descriptions. Then use jQuery to highlight the selected image and show the description for the selected image based upon it's index within the container.

```
// handle img click
$('#grid img').click(function(){

  // get index of the img that was clicked
  var idx = $(this).parent().index();

  // remove special style from all others
  $('#grid img').removeClass('highlight');

  // add a special style to the clicked image
  $(this).addClass('highlight');

  // hide all others
  $('#descriptions .panel').hide();

  // show desc for clicked img
  $('#descriptions .panel').eq(idx).show();

});
```